# Several JHipster microservices using PostgreSQL listening on same port

Tags: postgresql, jhipster

I have several microservices as well as the gateway, all using PostgreSQL. So all these services have a `postgresql.yml` file using the same port `5432`. This means I have to change the port numbers manually so I can start several instances of PostgreSQL without clashing.

When JHipster creates a new microservice it asks for the HTTP port (eg. 8081, 8082, 8083...). Why not do the same with PostgreSQL (5432, 5433, 5434) ? This way we will have one microservice running on 8081/5432, the other one on 8082/5433, 8083/5434...

WDYT ? Or is there another way ?

Comment: Are the microservice going to access the same data/database or the database is also different along with ports

Comment: You should have mentioned it's used to generate docker files. Could be a good idea: by default using an offset from the service port but still allowing to override it in some config file used by the generator. On the other hand, it may cause issues for people who don't use docker in dev as this force them to edit their jdbc url in application-dev.yml

Comment: @GaëlMarziou In production mode, I'm happy to have a single port, because that's what we have (one Postgres server with different DB schemas). But in dev mode, I have several Postgres (easier to manage). I see your point about people who don't use Docker. And what about having dev, docker and prod profiles ? With docker profile using port offset ?

Comment: A docker profile that could be combined with other profiles (like swagger profile) could be useful although it could be confusing for newbies.